# Best way to handle the fields which are getting writen out on “hover” state

Tags: experience-manager, 2013, siteedit

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 and the latest version of Experience manager on my website.

Currently I am looking for a better solution to make some fields editable through experience manager. I haven't found a good solution to write out fields for the basic html functionalities listed below.

1. How to make component link editable through experience manager.[one way is to write out the separate component presentation tag for the link, but I am looking for a better solution]
2. I am showing some component fields on mouse hover state of the html content. Wwhat will be the best way to make this field editable?
3. I have a slideshow banner in my application. Aach slide is a Tridion component and I want to make it editable through experience manager. Because of rich text interface on the HTML side it became little tough to come up with a good and generic solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This scenario is covered in Bart's [Having fun with Experience Manager, Page Regions and Widgets](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/having-fun-with-experience-manager) blog post on the Tridion Developer site. 
(See the section starting "*The last subject I want to address is that at some point you will come to an item which has no visible element showing on the website*")

He suggests using CSS and JavaScript to expose the hidden content when using Experience Manager with a `xpm-only` class.